# postfix discard or change Message-ID header based on another header line

Tags: postfix, smtp

I want to change the Message-ID header or better yet, discard it. I know everyone is going to ask "Why would you want to do that?" because I know it sounds weird to even write it.

Well I am developing a system that saves an incoming e-mail in EML format, changes it and sends it to the user, at some point the user can request to have the original EML sent to him/her. The issue is that when I re-send the EML it has the same Message-ID header which causes exchange servers to drop the re-send.

Of course I am hoping there is some option through postfix to do this, otherwise I will need to parse and change the EML but I rather not do that.

I tried to do this with "header_checks" and it works BUT I need to be able to do this conditionally, meaning only on a specific occasion, which I can identify by looking at the other headers, I want to remove the Message-ID.

Comment: You may be able to use the [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) parameter. See [Remove headers](https://posluns.com/guides/header-removal/) for an example that may work.

Comment: There are plenty of questions going in the same direction. What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks guys, I'll try the "headers_checks" I think this is the best lead so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I need to be able to do this conditionally, meaning only on a specific occasion, which I can identify by looking at the other headers, I want to remove the Message-ID.*

No you can't do it with header_checks. Postfix examines the rules on one header line at a time. In other words, the you can't modify one header line based on another header line. See [man 5 header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) in BUG section and [this thread](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/postfix/2010-05/0136.html) on postfix mailing list.

> Many  people  overlook  the  main limitations of header and body_checks rules.
>
> - These rules operate on one logical message header  or  one  body line at a time. A decision made for one line is not carried over to the next line.

Comment: Do you have another recommendation about how this can be done via postfix? Or do I have to create another script to do this prior to sending the mail?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you for this. My postfix experience with header modifications was little. [This link](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html) in postfix docs wasn't help either. Well, I suggest you to write the your header modification before sending it to postfix :)