# Conditional rewrite Postfix headers

Tags: postfix

On my website I have a form that is send to me by e-mail once filled out. The form mails with its own email address but has a Reply-to to the people who have filled out the form.

In Postfix I want to correct this to replace the From-address with the Reply-to address. I use this syntax in header_checks:

```
if !/^From:.*(form@domain1.com|form@domain2.com)/ 
  /^Reply-To:(.*)/ REPLACE From:$1 
endif
```

But it does not work. What do I do wrong?

Comment: No you can't do it with header_checks, see [this similar question](http://serverfault.com/q/654229/218590). Also, Why not correct it in the code?