# Postfix header conditional rewrite

Tags: debian, postfix, regex, alias, mail-forwarding

in my mail server I have a mailbox me@mrtsolutions.it and an alias ciao@mrtsolutions.it which send all to me@gmail.com.

Now when I send from user@gmail.com an email to ciao@mrtsolutions.it, I receive the mail in me@gmail.com.
Now I would like to rewrite mail header in forwarded messagge with From field set to forwarded@mrtsolutions.it and Reply-To field set to original sender.

My header_check file:

```
if /^To:.*(ciao@mrtsolutions.it|contact@mrtsolutions.it)/
/^From:(.+@.+).*$/ PREPEND Reply-To:$1
/^From:(.+@.+).*$/ REPLACE From: forwarded@mrtsolutions.it
endif
```

Where am I wrong? Nothing of this works

Answer (score 1):

I think this has already been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/654229/postfix-discard-or-change-message-id-header-based-on-another-header-line)

I suggest you look at these posts for a different approach using [postfix pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html):

- https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail
- http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Conditional-sender-rewrite-based-on-recipient-address-td93497.html

and just because I ran into this issue trying to avoid a loop:

- [Specifying a Postfix Instance to send outbound email](https://serverfault.com/questions/599140/specifying-a-postfix-instance-to-send-outbound-email)
- http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html